# Using the Publisher overview_version error and incomplete information displayed

Tags: wso2, wso2-es, wso2-governance-registry

I am seeing interesting behavior with the WSO2 Publisher for both Governance Registry as well as Enterprise Server when I am using self-defined asset types.  There are two items of concern - the one is that I can successfully save an asset type and capture details against it within the Carbon admin console.  This works and works well.

However, when I view the asset in the Publisher, only some of the values that has been captured in the admin console are visible.  All of the fields (labels) show up, however some are empty.  I can however view them successfully in the Admin Console.  What I also find interesting is that if I then update the entry in the Publisher and capture new values for the fields that aren't being displayed, I can see the changed values in the Admin Console - so certainly updating from the Publisher is reflected.  Once I've done the Publisher update, the values reflect as they've been captured.

The other dilemma is that when I want to capture a new asset from the Publisher itself, I get an error that the asset cannot be created.  The error is "Error while creating asset for the request due to overView_version is not provided. Please provide a value for overview_version since it is a required field".  I don't have an overview_version field defined within the asset definition.  Actually, there is no version information being captured at all as the asset won't go through a version change.

Any idea what could be causing this?  I've tried this under both WSO2 GREG (v5.0.0) as well as WSO2 ES (v2.0.0) and both exhibit the same behaviour.  At the moment I am using the Admin Console primarily to capture data, however I would prefer to use the Publisher as the dependency graphs are very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I know it may be a bit too late but I believe this is caused by the versionAttribute property defined in the {CARBON_HOME}/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/extensions/assets/default/asset.js:configure function [1].

Can you try setting this property to an empty string.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-store/blob/master/apps/publisher/extensions/assets/default/asset.js#L209

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because you haven't indicated that your not using version attribute in your artifact. To overcome the issue please find below code line in [asset.js](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-store/blob/v2.4.6/apps/publisher/extensions/assets/default/asset.js#L256) which is located in here(1).

```
versionAttribute: 'overview_version',
```

and change it to an empty string like below.

```
versionAttribute: ' ',
```

Now you have to restart the carbon server.

(1) - CARBON_HOME/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher/extensions/assets/default/asset.js